# CheckBoxFor Html helper's hidden field issue with serializeArray

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have a form like this.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedVal, new SelectList(Model.ValLst, "Value", "Name"))
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsPaid, new { @Id = "IsPaid"})
            </li>
        </ul>           
    </div>
</form>
```

I have to serialize this form as follows & I am operating on the serialized array

```
values = $('#myForm').serializeArray();

0: Object
name: "SelectedVal"
value: "BMV"

1: Object
name: "Id"
value: "123"

2: Object
name: "IsPaid"
value: "true"

3: Object
name: "IsPaid"
value: "false"
```

I am facing issue with the CheckBoxFor helper. As, it's creating a hidden field with value false & both hiddenfield & checkbox have the same id. So model value of the checkbox is false always, eventhough it's checked. i.e. while operating on the serialized array, the hidden field value overrides the checkbox value.

So I thought of ignoring hiddenfields while serializing. Like:

```
values = $('#myForm').find("input[type != 'hidden']").serializeArray();

0: Object
name: "Id"
value: "123"

1: Object
name: "IsPaid"
value: "true"
```

But, it is not working as I am not getting dropdown value. So, thought,DropDownListFor also uses hidden field. Any suggestion, how to send correct value of checkbox to controller. Something, like ignoring immediate hidden field  following checkbox or any other html helper or forcing the hidden field render before the checkbox.

Comment: Use `.serialize()` (not `.serializeArray()`). If your controller method has a parameter which is the model used in the view, your model will be correctly bound (and `DropDownListFor()` does not generate a hidden field and the hidden input associated with the checkbox does not have an `id`!)

Comment: I need to traverse through the serialized form & operate on it. So to use each() I am using Serialize array.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your code :)

Comment: Your edit does not show your script.

Comment: values = $('#myForm').find("input[type != 'hidden']").serializeArray();   This is the script I am using to restrict hidden field value from being serialized. But, I lost Dropdown value also

Comment: I mean show the script where you do the `$.each()` :) And `DropDownListFor()` does not generate a `<input>` - its generates a `<select>` and it is not hidden (although if your using a jquery plugin, the plugin may hide it). And the correct selector would be `find('input, select').not(':hidden')` but this will not solve your problem (despite what you may think)

Comment: $.each(values, function () {
                json[this.name] = this.value || '';
            });   The View has several partial-views. Each partial view is a form. So content of each partial view is passed at once to a controller using view model. So this is done for re-usability

Comment: There is no reason for that script at all. I suspect it's the result of  taking the wrong approach to solving another issue (but its not clear from your comment just what that is)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Checkbox always holds value true & the hidden field holds false always. But, for a checked checkbox, it's parent span holds a class "checked". So, before serializing we can keep the desired value in hidden field. Now, let it override.  If the parent span has class 'checked', then keep 'true' in the corresponding hidden field, else false.

```
        // traverse through all the checkboxes, check class of it's parent span

        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
            // id of hidden field is same as that of the check box
            var hdnFldId = "input[type='hidden']#" + $(this).attr('id');
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('checked'))
            {
                $(hdnFldId).val(true);
            }
            else {
                $(hdnFldId).val(false);
            }
        });
        values = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$('#myForm').serialize();`, not `$('#myForm').serializeArray();`.

`.serializeArray()` is posting back `IsPaid=[true, false]`, i.e and array of values which cannot be bound to a `boolean` property (it has nothing to do with the hidden input overriding the checkbox), where as `.serialize()` will post `IsPaid=true&IsPaid=false` which will be correctly bound to you model (the `DefaulModelBinder` reads the first value (`true`) and ignores any subsequent name/value pairs with the same name.

Side notes: `@Html.DropDownListFor()` does not generate a hidden input. Thhe hidden input generated by `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` does not have an `id` attribute and `new { @Id = "IsPaid"}` is pointless. The helper already generates that `id`

Comment: You are 100% correct. But, my requirement is totally different. It's already designed. I am just adding a partial view. A view has several partial views. Each partial view is a form. Id of these forms correspond to properties of the ViewModel used to bind the main view. So they have formed object of objects. Content of each partial view is in an unique object. Finally, the Object of objects is stringified & sent to an action on ajax. Hope, I make sense now

Comment: Not at all :) (and its still a poor design). But if your really want to do this, then use `var values = $('#myForm').serializeArray(); $.each(values, function () { // manipulate your data }); var data = $.param(values);`. The `$.params()` function correctly serializes the array so you can now use `$.post(url, data, function(..) { ... });` (or `$.ajax({ data: data, ....})` and it will be correctly bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`

Answer (score -1):

I missed select element. It should be

```
values = $('#myForm').find('input, select').not(':hidden').serializeArray();
```

Comment: Did you not understand my comment _"this will not solve your problem (despite what you may think)"_

Comment: @StephenMuecke It solved my problem. I can't explain my requirement fully. But, It's doing as expected. Thanks.

Comment: No it will not. Sorry to be harsh but clearly you have a lot to learn about MVC. The `CheckboxFor()` method generates the hidden input for a good reason - so when the checkbox is unchecked, it posts back `false`. Take  a case where you have a `bool` property where the default is `true` (set in the constructor). Now the user unchecks it - so in your case you don't post anything (unchecked checkboxes do not post back) so the value is set to `true`, despite the user thinking that they have just set it to false. Your just continuing to make more and more hacks to overcome a bad design.

Comment: I thought, I will send default value false from controller & there will be no issue if I ignore hidden field from serialization. But, it's not working.

Comment: You problem lies with your design. I have no idea what your `json[this.name] = ..` is doing but if your trying to manipulate the names of the values your posting then your going about it the wrong way. Your just writing hacks (and I see you have just accepted another one) to do what MVC can do out of the box. And as a side note, the hidden input generated by `CheckBoxFor()` does **not** have an `id` attribute and the code you have accepted does not work.